# Custom domains with Azure Websites (Multi tenant)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, multi-tenant, cname

This article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh534477.aspx#sec7 explains the below approach on how to let customers add custom domains and map to your application.

---

As an alternative you could allow each tenant to create its own DNS entry that maps a domain or subdomain owned by the tenant to one of your application’s DNS names. For example, Adatum could create the following DNS entry in its DNS configuration:

surveys.adatum.com CNAME adatum.tailspinsurveys.com

Or Adatum could create the following entry:

surveys.adatum.com CNAME www.tailspinsurveys.net

In either case you could use the custom domain name in your ASP.NET routing by using the technique suggested in option 3 above, or use the Request.Url class in your code to identify the domain.

---

I can achieve this so far with subdomains but when I create the CNAME below to my application I end up with a 404 (Web App not found). I don't want to have to add a custom domain inside azure for each customer. I'd like to automate the process for my SaaS site.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> when I create the CNAME below to my application I end up with a 404 (Web App not found)

It seems you do not configure the custom domain correctly. I would suggest you use [Dig Web interface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/) to trace your DNS domain. Please also check your steps from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name) to ensure the custom domain is configure correctly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I guess the functionality I need to to not have to add a custom domain in the portal for every tenant? (plus as I understand there is a 500 limit on this), which hinders the multi-tenant approach when we reach 1000's of users. The CNAME should be setup by them and we should be able to automate adding or clearing their domain.

Comment: What solution did you go with? We have a similar setup